# Ansible UNTIL Loop based on output

Tags: loops, ansible, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I was using the UNTIL logic for Ansible checking the beanstalk Health. The expected behavior is that when the Health status or the output turns to **Green** then the loop will end. However it seems the output is already green but the loop still reached to the last count and the ansible job failed. This is the ansible UNTIL loop I'm using

```
- name: CHECKING IF THE BEANSTALK IS HEALTHY
    shell: "eb status | grep Health | sed -e 's/Health://g' | sed 's/^ *//g'"
    register: result
    until: result.stdout.find("Green") != -1
    retries: 10
    delay: 60
    args:
      chdir: "{{ playbook_dir }}/{{ env }}/my-app"
```

I'm just getting the Health value, if the color is **Green** then the loop should finish, however in this code I'm using, the health is already green for the least 4rth time checked by loop but still it reached to the last count and failed.

here is the actual checking

```
my-pc$ eb status | grep Health | sed -e 's/Health://g' | sed 's/^ *//g'
Grey

my-pc$ eb status | grep Health | sed -e 's/Health://g' | sed 's/^ *//g'
Grey

my-pc$ eb status | grep Health | sed -e 's/Health://g' | sed 's/^ *//g'
Grey

my-pc$ eb status | grep Health | sed -e 's/Health://g' | sed 's/^ *//g'
Green
```

Actual output without trim

```
my-pc$ eb status
Environment details for: app-mong-lagot-ka
  Application name: lagot-ulo-mo
  Region: us-east-1
  Deployed Version: None
  Environment ID: e-potmaohab
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-northeast-1::platform/PHP 7.0 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.9.0
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: app-mong-lagot-ka.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com
  Updated: 2020-02-28 20:43:14.348000+00:00
  Status: Ready
  Health: Green
```

Comment: Your code as written seems to work for me. What if you replace your task with a simple `command: eb status`, register the output, and then display it in a subsequent `debug` task...do you see the output you expect?

Comment: Hi larsks, not yet tried to place debug, can you share on how was it formatted in the ansible script block?

Comment: Not easily in a comment, no, but pretty much exactly how you have it (although your indenting seems to be off: everything in your task should be indented at the same level as `name:`).

Answer (score 0):

> ***Ansible: How to `retries` `until` specific term is in `stdout`?***

I understand that you like to [Retrying a task until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met) and the message `Green` shows up in `stdout`.

Based on the documentation and your example a minimal playbook

```bash
~/test$ echo 'Health: Grey' > health.log
```

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: CHECKING IF HEALTHY
    shell: "grep Health health.log | sed -e 's/Health: //g'" # | sed 's/^ *//g'
    register: result
    until: result.stdout.find("Green") != -1
    retries: 10 # times
    delay: 1 # seconds
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************
FAILED - RETRYING: CHECKING IF HEALTHY (10 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: CHECKING IF HEALTHY (9 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: CHECKING IF HEALTHY (8 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: CHECKING IF HEALTHY (7 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: CHECKING IF HEALTHY (6 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: CHECKING IF HEALTHY (5 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: CHECKING IF HEALTHY (4 retries left).
FAILED - RETRYING: CHECKING IF HEALTHY (3 retries left).
```

and stop soon after an

```bash
~/test$ echo 'Health: Green' > health.log
```

with

```yaml
TASK [CHECKING IF HEALTHY] *******************
changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP ***********************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1
```